# Determining Bases of Space Spanned by (perhaps) Infinitely Many Matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've been studying vector space bases and have had rather hard time to figure it. Most of the times I read examples dealing with vector space of n-tuple vectors with finite numbers of it to concern with (e.g. vector space spanned by $(v_1, v_2, ..., v_p)$) and eventually had fun with it. But I'm rather clueless what if the space is spanned by a set of matrix? The following problem makes me pretty confused.

Let $M_{2\times2}$ be the set of all real-valued $2\times2$ matrix and $K = \{A \in M_{2\times2} | A = A^T \}$
a. Show that $K$ is a subspace of $M_{2\times2}$
b. Find bases for K.

This is my approach:

a. If $K$ is a subspace of $M_{2\times2}$, then $K$ must be satisfies closure under addition and scalar multiplication. Let $P = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{bmatrix}$, $Q = \begin{bmatrix} d & e \\ e & f \end{bmatrix}$ be two matrix in $K$. Let $R = P + Q = \begin{bmatrix} a+d & b+e \\ b+e & c+f \end{bmatrix}$ . Then $R$ is in $K$ because $R = R^T$. Therefore $K$ is closed under addition. Let $S = kA = \begin{bmatrix} ka & kb \\ kb & kc \end{bmatrix}, k $ is a constant. Then $S$ in $K$ because $S = S^T$. Therefore, $K$ is closed under scalar multiplication. Thus, $K$ is a subscpace of $M$. Please point me to mistakes I made if any.

b. ?? At first, my answer was simply $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & c\end{bmatrix}$ for any real-valued $a, b, c$. But my friend argued that bases must not contain any variable at all (Is this true?), then I realized that $K$ contain infinitely many matrix satisfying the property. Then I think of this:  $ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ because any matrix in $K$ could be expressed in these two matrix (correct me if i'm wrong), but I simply just pure guessing, don't know how I derive these. After all, what is the intuition behind "a space spanned by set of matrix"? What if I break these matrix into $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and set them as bases for $K$? Edit: Now I'm considering $ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, but again this is just a guessing. If I just let the bases be the set of standard bases, is it OK?

Last question: Generally, can I view a $n\times n$ matrix as a set of n-tuple vector? If so, can I say that  space spanned by matrix is equivalent to space spanned by set of $n$ n-tuple vectors?

Any help will be very appreciated. If there exist solution to my problem above, kindly link me to it. I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to (a) looks good.  For (b), your two matrices
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
are linearly independent, but they do not span $K$.  For instance, you cannot express
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
as a linear combination of the two matrices that you gave.  The defining equation for
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
\in K \subset M_{2 \times 2}
$$
is $b = c$, so we can decompose it as:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & d \end{bmatrix}
&= \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & b \\ b & 0 \end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix} \\
&= a \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
+ b \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
+ c \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
You can check that the three matrices
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
are linearly independent; hence, they form a basis for $K$.

Comment: It looks like you edited your question to suggest the correct basis set.  Are you convinced that it is a basis, though?

Comment: Well, the idea came from nowhere when I was about to sleep. Now I'm pretty convinced that is. Thanks!